# Ranking in Google Sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, ranking, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have some data about people on my Google Sheet and they are given some points based on their activities. What I want in the next column is that their rank based on their points. I would change the points manually on a regular basis and accordingly, their rank should be changed automatically with a formula.

At present the data ranging from A1 to J50 where row 1 is the header. I need the rank in K.

I would like to know to rank in two ways.
One in numerical. Like, Rank 1, 2, 3, etc.
Other in text, 'Outstanding', 'Good', or any text.

Comment: Have you looked into the [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150) function?

Comment: Thanks for reminding about the sort function. Although it can sort the whole rage it won't serve my purpose as I need ranks in another column. As a workaround, I can simply enter numbers in order outside the sorting rage and consider it as rank. But the problem here is if there are people with same points then the value (static) I would enter outside the range will assign different ranks even though they have same points. Is there any other way out?

Comment: _Although it can sort the whole range it won't serve my purpose as I need ranks in another column_ No worries - are those other rank requirements apparent in your question? For example, I can see that you want to sort on "text" but that is fraught with problems because, unless you carefully stage manage the text values to rank in the same order as the numeric values, text ranking is pretty meaningless. @Anna notes this in her answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the rank function is your best option for the ranking portion, and you can use a vlookup for the ranking if the mapping of your values won't change at all.

[Here is a sample workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15JvDoeS71y_cmbGQ80T-o77d-7iFFZOVus3_4jhQEWI/edit?usp=sharing) I threw together with the formulas. If you want to have the text ranking be dynamic as well, you'll need to provide thresholds for each value (top 20% are 'Outstanding', next 30% are 'Good', etc).

Hope this is close to what you're looking for!

Comment: It looked good even where same point repeats but I look closely there is an issue. Al same points are given same rank and that is correct too. But after the repeating point the ranking doesn't come correct. It skips some ranks.

Example:

Name         Points    Ranks

Bob               3 6
Joe               8 2
Sam               1 7
Jen               4 3
Kim               9 1
Kip               4 3
Sue               4 3

In above example Point 4 repeats 3 times and Rank against point 4 is 3 which is given correctly. However, for Point 3 Rank should have been 4 but it assigned 6.

Comment: or is it my mistake in understanding?
If that is the correct way of it, then this is not close to what I am looking for as you said but this is what exactly I am looking for.

Comment: It's skipping numbers where users are tied - If Janet and Sally are tied for first, and Joan is the next highest, she'll say 3 since she's in 3rd place since there is no second place. That's a normal output for rankings

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(RANK(B2:B, B2:B)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(RANK(B2:B, B2:B)), {
 1, "the best"; 
 2, "great";
 3, "good one";
 5, "lama xD"}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: There's a wrinkle here. Because the formula goes in cell C2 &/or D2, if one sorts by Points (whether ascending or descending) the formula cells are moved too, and some cells in Column C and/or D may be blank. FWIW, I preferred vlookup for getting the status; it overcomes a bunch of contingencies of points and ranks.

Comment: it could go in C1 / D1 and be frozen if needed